# CSS Display block issue

Tags: html, wordpress, css, themes

I'm not a CSS genius, but what I am trying to accomplish here is very very simple. I'm using a theme with a navigation menu. The list items of the navigation menu gets mixed up. Example:

```
MenuItem1 MenuItem2 MenuItem3 MenuItem4
     MenuItem5     MenuItem6       MenuItem7
```

I am trying to align everything like the following:

```
MenuItem1 MenuItem2 MenuItem3 MenuItem4
MenuItem5 MenuItem6 MenuItem7
```

In the passed I could easily achieve this by using float. But this template uses:
Display: Block.
I've googled a lot and the solution should be very easy, **but in this specific theme I get lost.**

The URL is: http://www.radio-suriname.nl

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you trying to left align the items in `#top-menu`? If so, set `#top-menu { text-align: left; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like the following?

```
.menu-item {
    width: 180px;
}

.menu-item a{
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Yes I did, no luck

Comment: Hmm, I have tried it in Firefox and Chrome and seems that it works. Did you add my code to the end of file style.css? Just a screenshot what I mean: http://take.ms/MqeR2   Another way is to add this code in the HEAD tag, example: http://take.ms/sdPbH

Comment: hungerstar has a better solution than me :)

Comment: You were right dude! Damn I feel so stupid now.. ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
#top-menu{
  text-align: justify;
}
```

just put this in your css file to achieve the result you whant.[image]